# Change column label on grid (PeopleSoft)

Tags: peoplesoft

I'm having problems changing the label of a column on a PeopleSoft grid.

I have this code on the RowInit event of the main record:

```
Local Grid &Grid;
Local GridColumn &Column;
&Grid = GetGrid(Panel.V91MG_BI_INGMAN, "GRID");
&Column = &Grid.GetColumn("DATO_01");
&Column.Label = "Test";
```

The grid is composed of a Table record and a Derived/Work record. I need to rename the columns of the Derived record.

This is how the page looks like on designer view:

[image]
When I test my page, I receive the following message:

[image]

I know the grid is being set correctly, as I can change its label using &Grid.Label = "Hi".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your peoplecode is correct so far. You should move this code to the page activate event.

Did you set the page field name for this column?

[image]

Comment: Man, you rock !!! I didn't know I had to set the Page Field Name. I thought it would automatically take the table column name. Thanks a lot, it's working now.

Comment: By the way, it's still working, even if the code is not on the "Page Activate" event. I have this code on the Row Init of the main record.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change label only you can do same without writing code.

1. Go to page fields properties.
2. Select tab 'Label'
3. Select Text Radio and enter column label.

[image: Image1][image: Image 2]

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I need to change the name dynamically. I need to read the possible values from a SQL query.